# Angular to s3 upload images

Tags: angularjs, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

I want to directly send the images to AWS S3 bucket using ng-file-upload. The request I am sending doesn't seem to be getting processed. The request is like follows:

```
                  Upload.upload({
                    url: credentials.url, //S3 upload url including bucket name
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        key: "blob", // the key to store the file on S3, could be file name or customized
                        AWSAccessKeyId: credentials.fields.AWSAccessKeyId,
                        acl: 'public-read', // sets the access to the uploaded file in the bucket: private, public-read, ...
                        policy: credentials.fields.policy, // base64-encoded json policy (see article below)
                        signature: credentials.fields.signature, // base64-encoded signature based on policy string (see article below)
                        "Content-Type": file.type, // content type of the file (NotEmpty)
                        file: file
                    }
                });
```

Can someone tell me where i am going wrong with this?

Comment: Check the "Net" tab in your browser's developer console and see what the actual response is from S3 when this request is sent. We're looking for the HTTP response code and any messages that might be coming back.

Comment: I created another bucket and repeated the same procedure. Now at least there is an error : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at /*link to bucket*/ (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: It sounds like you didn't go through all the steps listed under **Amazon AWS S3 Upload** here: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#amazon-aws-s3-upload In particular it sounds like you haven't enabled CORS on your S3 bucket.

Comment: Here is the CORS config I am using at the moment                         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>5000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

Comment: That CORS configuration looks good except for a stray semicolon in there.

Comment: Sorry for the typo...any ideas what might be wrong with the bucket config or angular side?